# How to vectorize a rolling list comprehension over pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have the following list comprehension:

```
[(foo(df.iloc[old_row[0]:old_row[1]].cov(), df.iloc[new_row[0]:new_row[1]].cov()), new_row)
 for new_row in new_rows_list if old_row != new_row]
```

where,

- `df` is an 20000 rows 50 columns `pandas.DataFrame`
- `old_row` is a `tuple` which gives coordinates to the
  rows, where `old_row[0]` < `old_row[1]` (e.g. (50, 100))
- `new_row` is the same as `old_row`, but with different values
- `new_rows_list` is a `list` of the `new_row` `tuples`

Essentially what I am trying to achieve is to do perform `foo` on two `pandas.DataFrames`, where one is the same and the other one changes by the loop.
The loop simply takes chunks of the `DataFrame` consecutively (e.g. first from row 0 to 50, then 51 to 100, then 101 to 150 etc.).

I tried using `np.vectorize`, however as both `new_rows_list` and `df` are iterables, I cannot achieve any results with this function.

The whole output returns a list of tuples, where one tuple is (`foo`'s result, `new_row`)

I am sure there is a way to escape this loop, but I am stuck here.

Let me know if more clarification is needed, in case my explanation is not sufficient.

Comment: you might add an example; [mcve]